# How can I change this WinSCP script to only to download .csv files and no other files?

Tags: powershell, ftp, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I would like to change this [PowerShell WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_delete_after_successful_download) which is connecting to an SFTP Server, to only download `.csv` files.

What part of the following portion of the script would I need to change?

```
# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Synchronize files to local directory, collect results
$synchronizationResult = $session.SynchronizeDirectories(
    [WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local, $localPath, $remotePath, $False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a [filemask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) using [`TranferOptions.FileMask`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#filemask) to  restrict the synchronization to specific extensions.

```
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.FileMask = "*.csv"

$synchronizationResult = $session.SynchronizeDirectories(
    [WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local, $localPath, $remotePath, $False, $False,
    [WinSCP.SynchronizationCriteria]::Time, $transferOptions)
```